# Laravel: Take n model instances from database based on date

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

As the question states, I'm trying to get from the database, **from multiple tables**, `n` (variable) number of records ordered by earliest date.

The tables don't really have much in common so not sure if a join is the way to go.

I have at least 4 models and at this moment I have two possible ways to in my mind:

Either find out which dates are the next `n`, and try to build my list from there, or take `n` from each and then compared them and sort them by the date (which seems a bit trivial)

How should I go with this one?

**Later Edit:**

I would like to get an overview of following: `invoices` to be cashed in, `expenses` to be paid, `activities` which will follow, and expected `events`, so let's assume that those are our tables.

Tables look something like:

`invoices`:

```
| id | customer_id | invoice_no | issue_date | due_date | paid_on | amount | vat | total | company_id created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |
```

`expenses`:

```
| id | name | amount | due_date | paid_on |  user_id |  company_id | expense_category_id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |
```

`events` and `activities` have somewhat the same structure including a name, a location, some booleans for confirmed, etc. and the date field

**Even Later edit:**

I still haven't found any "Eloquent" solution, and I'm not sure at this moment if I could collect all the data I need in only one query but this is what I've been able to come with so far (`invoices` and `expenses`), for a specific `company`:

```
public function nextEvents($limit) {

$results = \DB::select(\DB::raw('SELECT `due_date` AS `date`, `total` as `amount`,  CONCAT("Invoice #", `invoice_no`) as `title`,  "income" as `type` FROM `invoices` WHERE `paid_on` IS NULL AND `company_id` = '.$this->id.'
UNION ALL
SELECT `due_date` as `date`, `amount`, `name` as `title`,  "expense" as `type` FROM `expenses` WHERE `paid_on` IS NULL AND `company_id` = '.$this->id.' ORDER BY `date` LIMIT '.$limit));


return $results;
```

}

Comment: You probably should show structure of the model to get a better understanding.